# SQL Server Enterprise Edition: Use more than 4GB of RAM on a 32 bit Machine?

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, memory

I would like to install SQL Server 2008 on a 32 bit machine.

I have read that it is possible with the SQL Server Enterprise edition to increase the memory over the 4GB?

Is this true? Any documentation? I couldn't find anything solid from Microsoft or anywhere else reputable except SQL server forum posts!

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://www.eraofdata.com/blog/2008/10/sql-server-memory-configuration/) the type of information you're looking for as a starting point?

Comment: Yes, that is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this question regarding the Windows /3GB switch, and PAE.  [/3GB switch on win2k3 server with 6gb RAM and PAE](https://serverfault.com/questions/44446/3gb-switch-on-win2k3-server-with-6gb-ram-and-pae)

Answer (score 0):

Check these resources:

- [PAE and /3GB and AWE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chadboyd/pae-and-3gb-and-awe-oh-my)
- [Memory Management - Demystifying /3GB](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/memory-management-demystifying-3gb/ba-p/372333)